# View can't find field

Tags: python, xml, odoo

So I made a basic model that has the following code in it:

```
class mrp_bom(models.Model):
_inherit = "mrp.bom"

barcode = fields.Char('Barcode', size=64)
```

Nothing special and then a view that goes with it:

```
     <record id="myform_mrp_bom_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">mrp.bom.form_myform</field>
        <field name="model">mrp.bom</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp.mrp_bom_form_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//notebook/page/field/tree/field[@name='product_id']" position="before">
                <field name="barcode" context="{'default_supply_method':'produce'}"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

I don't know why but I keep getting the error that field 'barcode' does not exist. When I check in the database structure I can see that the field is there under 'mrp.bom'.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View part is proper. You need to try with this code in your .py side

```
class mrp_bom_line(models.Model):
    _inherit = "mrp.bom.line"

    barcode = fields.Char('Barcode', size=64)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have added field Barcode in mrp.bom model.
But, you tried to display in the mrp.bom.line..

Comment: Didn't know that in 8 you had the mrp.bom.line class, thanks! But now it changed to 'Field `message_follower_ids` does not exist'